# Unityで作成したアプリをcodesignで署名したら開かなくなった

Tags: macos, unity3d

Unityで作成したアプリを公証を得るために、署名してアップロードする作業を行っていたのですが、`codesign`で署名したあとのアプリが開かなくなってしまいました。

署名前には問題なく起動、動作していたアプリが署名後はアプリ自体が開かなくなってしまいます。
開こうとすると、

```
The last time you opened "アプリ名", it was force quit while reopening windows.
Do you want to try to reopen its window again?
```

のメッセージが出ますが、これは開こうと試して、何度も強制終了しているためだと思います。

署名前のアプリが起動することは何度も確認しています。
システム環境設定 > セキュリティとプライバシー > 一般 を見て実行許可できるか確認しましたが、特に表示がありませんでした。
そもそも自身で署名したあとのアプリはGateKeeperによって起動ができないようにされているのでしょうか？
"`codesign app not open`"などで調べましたが、欲しい情報に当たることはできませんでした。
署名前後で.app内に_CodeSignatureが増えていることが起動の妨げになるなんてことはないですよね...?

**追記(2020/02/12)**
・`codesign`が成功しているかどうかについて、`xcrun altool`を使ってAppleに公証を得られるか確かめたところ、ちゃんと承認されました
・空のプロジェクトを作成して同じ工程を試しましたが、結果は変わりませんでした
・[こちらのサイト](https://gist.github.com/dpid/270bdb6c1011fe07211edf431b2d0fe4)を参考にして署名を行っています

**環境**
Unity 2019.3.0f6
macOS Catalina 10.15.3

署名前の.appの中身
[image: 署名前]

署名後の.appの中身
[image: 署名後]

Comment: マルチポスト: https://teratail.com/questions/239979

Comment: １）codesignで署名する前のアプリは今も開くことができますか？２）問題のアプリとは別のアプリをcodesignで署名すると同じ現象が発生しますか？

Comment: 1) 署名前のアプリは問題なく開き、正常動作します。 2) 空のプロジェクトを作って同様の工程(ビルド→動作確認→署名→動作確認)を行いましたが、結果は同じで開かなくなってしまいました。

Comment: アプリの問題ではなさそうですね。署名前アプリと署名後のアプリについてdtrussを実行し、結果を比較すると、書名後のアプリに何が起きているかわかるかもしれません。dtrussを実行するのはUnityに対してかもしれません。-pオプションがあるので、Unityのトレースも取れると思います。私はUnityもmacOSも未経験なので見当違いのコメントかもしれません、Linuxに置き換えて考えた方法です。

Comment: すみません、dtrussというのを使ったことがないので分からないのですがdtruss "open -a AAA.app"みたいな感じでいいんですかね。まだプロテクションがオンになってるとかで実行はできてないんですけど。

Comment: Unityが立ち上がった状態で、別にターミナルを立ち上げ、UnityのプロセスIDを`ps`コマンドで調べる。`dtruss -af -p UnityのプロセスID`を実行しておいて、Unityを操作するとターミナルにトレースログが表示されるはず。